# SQLite from android get path like indexes with recursive query

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, recursive-cte

I have this table named items with following columns and rows.

```
id   item_name   parentId
--------------------------
1    Item 1         0
2    Item 2         1
3    Item 3         2
4    Item 4         1
5    Item 5         2
6    Item 6         3
7    Item 7         6
8    Item 8         7
```

I could measure the level of rows parent by recursive CTE, but I still need to get the path as this format: 1.1.1, 1.2.1 ...
This is my current query:

```
with recursive items_cache (lvl, id, item_name, parent_id) as (
    select 0 as lvl, id, item_name, parent_id
    from items
    where parent_id = 0
  union all
    select items_cache.lvl + 1, items.id, items.item_name, items.parent_id
    from items_cache    
    join items  on items_cache.id = items.parent_id
    order by items_cache.lvl+1 desc, items.id
)
select
    lvl,
    *
from items_cache
```

Desired results:

```
id   item_name   parentId   lvl       path_index
-------------------------------------------------
1    Item 1         0        0        1
2    Item 2         1        1        1.1
3    Item 3         2        2        1.1.1
6    Item 6         3        3        1.1.1.1
7    Item 7         6        4        1.1.1.1.1
8    Item 8         7        5        1.1.1.1.1.1
5    Item 5         2        2        1.1.2
4    Item 4         1        1        1.2
9    Item 9         0        0        2
```

How can I do that in SQLite? The SQLite version that android runs is 3.21, so it does not support window functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive cte to get the level of each `id`, then `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to get the rank of each `id` under its parent and another recursive cte that will conatenate the row numbers:

```
WITH 
  levels AS (
    SELECT *, 0 lvl FROM items
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i.*, l.lvl + 1 
    FROM items i INNER JOIN levels l
    ON l.id = i.parentId 
  ),
  row_numbers AS (
    SELECT id, item_name, parentId, MAX(lvl) lvl,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parentId, lvl ORDER BY id) rn 
    FROM levels
    GROUP BY id, item_name, parentId
  ),
  cte AS (
    SELECT id, item_name, parentId, lvl, rn || '' path_index
    FROM row_numbers
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.id, r.item_name, r.parentId, r.lvl, 
           c.path_index || '.' || r.rn
    FROM row_numbers r INNER JOIN cte c
    ON r.parentId = c.id 
  )
SELECT * 
FROM cte  
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(LENGTH(path_index))
ORDER BY path_index
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ee72e9a328e23f51b736ac225a21f957).

If your version of SQLite does no support window functions use:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM levels l2 
 WHERE l2.parentId = l1.parentId AND l2.lvl = l1.lvl AND l2.id <= l1.id) rn
```

instead of:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parentId, lvl ORDER BY id) rn
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a31d5090929776cd311e6bb6e7cc2e48).

Results:

| id | item_name | parentId | lvl | path_index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Item 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | Item 2 | 1 | 1 | 1.1 |
| 3 | Item 3 | 2 | 2 | 1.1.1 |
| 6 | Item 6 | 3 | 3 | 1.1.1.1 |
| 7 | Item 7 | 6 | 4 | 1.1.1.1.1 |
| 8 | Item 8 | 7 | 5 | 1.1.1.1.1.1 |
| 5 | Item 5 | 2 | 2 | 1.1.2 |
| 4 | Item 4 | 1 | 1 | 1.2 |
| 9 | Item 9 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

Comment: I'm getting error when I try to run in android SQL, the error says: near "(": syntax error: WITH
  levels AS (
    SELECT *, 0 lvl FROM items
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i.*, l.lvl + 1
    FROM items i INNER JOIN levels l

Comment: @alexandre9865 The version of SQLite that you use in Android is old and does not support ctes and window functions.

Comment: The recursive part works well, my query in question was fine on android

Comment: @alexandre9865 ctes are supported since version 3.8.3 and window functions since version 3.25.0. Check your version.

Comment: SQLite from android is version 3.21. :/

Comment: @alexandre9865 then try this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a31d5090929776cd311e6bb6e7cc2e48, but it will not be as fast as the query with ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: I saw that the order by does not work well when Table data has more than 10 items, the 10th item appears followed by path_index starting by 1 instead of be followed by 9 number, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @alexandre9865 can you post sample data for this case here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ee72e9a328e23f51b736ac225a21f957

Comment: Done 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=151fc93af67ba726d0d3041abf48fe1c

Comment: @alexandre9865 check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b95aeeb25b8bdb3eda4cd8291f8e8346

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to compute the path index for each entry at a given iteration, and then use string concatenation with another recursive CTE:

```
with recursive to_r as (
   select row_number() over (order by i.id) r, i.* from items i
),
cte(id, name, parent, lvl, ind) as (
   select i.id, i.item_name, i.parentId, 0, (select sum(i1.parentId = i.parentId and i1.r < i.r) from to_r i1) + 1 from to_r i where i.parentId = 0
   union all
   select i1.id, i1.item_name, i1.parentId, i.lvl+1, (select sum(i2.parentId = i1.parentId and i2.r < i1.r) from to_r i2) + 1 from cte i join to_r i1 on i1.parentId = i.id
   
),
cte1(id, name, parent, lvl, ind, lvl1) as (
   select i.id, i.name, i.parent, i.lvl, case when i.lvl != 0 then "1." || i.ind else i.ind end, case when i.lvl != 0 then i.lvl-1 else i.lvl end from cte i
   union all
   select i.id, i.name, i.parent, i.lvl, "1." || i.ind, i.lvl1-1 from cte1 i where i.lvl1 > 0
)
select id, name, parent, lvl, ind from cte1 where lvl1 = 0 order by ind;
```

Comment: I'm getting error when I try to run in android SQL, the error says: 
near "(": syntax error: with recursive to_r as (
   select row_number() over (

Comment: @alexandre9865 As forpas mentioned, you might need to check your version of SQLite.

Comment: In fact, I have no support for window functions